# JSON - Not working in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I tried few thing to fix, Nothing helped.

in server side script,

```
 $array['content'] = "test";
 echo json_encode($array);
```

This is working in javascript. But

```
 $array['content'] = "<p>test</p>";
 echo json_encode($array);
```

Not working. If i add any html tag, it is not working. 
But they all are working in firefox and chrome.

This is the js handling the return value.

```
 function showResponse(responseText)  {
     $('.form_result').html(responseText.formData);
      alert(responseText.formData);
 }

 function submitButton1() {

    var options = {
        beforeSubmit:  showRequest,  // pre-submit callback
        success:       showResponse,  // post-submit callback
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false
    };

    // bind form using 'ajaxForm'
    $('#form').ajaxSubmit(options);
 }

     header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: 0");
```

Added the above two lines in php file.

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

Added the above in html file which handling the js. Still no use.

What could be the problem?
additionally, i dont see any error or warning in IE.

Comment: if the IE 8 native JSON feature is the problem, you can always overwrite it with the correct implementation from https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Comment: How do i use that? I don't see any example or steps to implement this. Should i just need to include them?

Comment: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js#L162 that's the bit you should modify to patch ie8

Comment: do a browser check, and if you're in ie 8 (or maybe just ie generally) overwrite the global JSON object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Explorer 8 doesn't support CORS in the XMLHttpRequest object which jQuery is using
ie8   uses XDomainRequest object

jQuery doesn't support XDomainRequest  by default.

check this [An update is available for the native JSON feature in Internet Explorer 8](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976662)

Comment: I didn't see anything any mention of domains in the question. why do you think it is a CORS issue?

Comment: so, without using the update, how do i fix it? I cant expect users to install this update.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what's the problem, but if disable `enctype="multipart/form-data"` all works fine.
I guess it's ajax form plugin problem.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but if you search for XMLHttpRequest object existing, and it doesn't, then implement your own ajax call.

Also check if JSON exists, and if doesn't then include json.js from just download it from the github and dynamically add it.