# how to make json work for ie7, ie8?

Tags: jquery, json, internet-explorer

I have used jquery for my page and all browsers but in IE it's not working and after a lot of struggle I came to know it was because json is not working and I tried placing this code and even after then it's not working.

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <script src="http://www.json.org/json2.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

So, how can I make json to work for ie7, ie8...?

---

I've something like this:

```
<?php
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
$link1 = 'index.php?Itemid=546';
$link2 = 'index.php?Itemid=540';
?>
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <script src="http://www.json.org/json2.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){  
var $morenews = $('<a>',{
    class: 'all-news-link',
    href: <?php echo json_encode( $link1 ); ?>
});
```

Comment: "JSON is not working" -- what *exactly* is not working?

Comment: Is it possible that your site is https and you try to download http ?. also dont count on json.org to be alive forever.

Comment: closely related to [JSON - Not working in Internet Explorer 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976801/json-not-working-in-internet-explorer-8)

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON on IE6 (IE7)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503175/json-on-ie6-ie7)

Comment: And where do you use JSON in javascript right now? How do you know that it is not working? `json_encode( $link1 )` is in php and will result in `href: "index.php?Itemid=540"` in the final page. (You don't use `JSON.parse` or `JSON.stringify` in the code you showed)

Comment: after the variable defined....

Answer (score 1):

The file you're trying to link to is not there (404 page).

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503175/json-on-ie6-ie7).